# Using a MEDIAN IF function in Excel as an index?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have my Median If function as 
`=MEDIAN(IF($A$6:$A$200=$L$5,D6:D200))`
and I want to know if I can wrap this in an INDEX function to return a value on the row of the calculated median, but in a different column (probably using MATCH I guess)? I've looked at a couple of sources online but I'm struggling to come up with a formula to do this.

The A column is a list of organisations, and the D column is a cumulative frequency that the median would be found in (or rather the range it would be found in so wouldn't be an exact match). I then want when my index has found the value in the D column, to retrieve the corresponding value in that row but from the B column. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes use MATCH to return the relative location:

```
 =INDEX($B$6:$B$200,MATCH(MEDIAN(IF($A$6:$A$200=$L$5,D6:D200)),D6:D200,0))
```

Depending on ones version of Excel this formula may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, this works in terms of it looks like it's using the right columns to INDEX and MATCH, but my MEDIAN seems off. So the values in frequency table currently go to 490 so I would expect it to pull the value from where 245 would lie, but it's pulling the value from the range of 377 - 395, which is just over 75%. Do you know why this would be? The MEDIAN function is looking for the median in the D column right?

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to confirm it an array formula?

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned this, so I get a value of 22 where the range in column D is 413 - 431 out of 490 when I use array formula. Both ways are giving higher values than expected.

Comment: Median is the middle value.  for example `1,4,5` the median would be `4` it is not the Average.

Comment: Yeah I know that much, so I have a list of 28 numbers and expect it to take the 14+15 avg, this is returning the 21st or 23rd value depending whether it is done as an array or not.

Comment: Then your data is right leaning.  More numbers on the upper side than the lower.  If you want average use average, but you will need to make the match search a `1` instead of `0` and sort your data on column D ascending.